# Setting focus by id AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-material

Upon clicking `+` button, the focus is shifted to another input field in HTML. I want to keep the focus on the current input field unless the user clicks on another input field. That's when I want to move the focus to the clicked input field.

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <md-input-container  class="md-block" flex="50">
        <input required id="circleTimeWordListEditText" type="text" placeholder="Words List" ng-model="circleTime.word"/>

        <div ng-messages="$error">
            <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
</div>

<div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" type="submit"
               ng-click="circleTime.onAddButtonClicked()">+
    </md-button>
</div>
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
document.getElementById('circleTimeWordListEditText').focus();
```

and I have tried this as well but it gives me NOSEL error.

```
angular.element('circleTimeWordListEditText').focus();
```

I tried this solution too:

```
mainApp.factory('focus', function($timeout, $window) {
    return function(id) {
        // timeout makes sure that it is invoked after any other event has been triggered.
        // e.g. click events that need to run before the focus or
        // inputs elements that are in a disabled state but are enabled when those events
        // are triggered.
        $timeout(function() {
            var element = $window.document.getElementById(id);
            if(element)
                element.focus();
        });
    };
});

mainApp.directive('eventFocus', function(focus) {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        elem.on(attr.eventFocus, function() {
            focus(attr.eventFocusId);
        });

        // Removes bound events in the element itself
        // when the scope is destroyed
        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            elem.off(attr.eventFocus);
        });
    };
});


onAddButtonClicked : function(elem) {
            //do stuff

            focus('circleTimeWordListEditText');
            /*var temp = document.getElementById('circleTimeWordListEditText');
            alert(temp);
            temp.focus();
            angular.element('circleTimeWordListEditText');
            angular.element('circleTimeWordListEditText').focus();*/
        }
    },
```

but it doesn't work either.

What is the recommended solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use the following snippet.

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('circleTimeWordListEditText');
var angularEl = angular.element(myEl);

angularEl.focus();
```

Comment: I just tested it, and it works here. Are you sure your function is being called on the button click? How does your function look in your controller?

Comment: Yes. I print the log when your code snippet is executed

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. This worked for me. I hope this works for you too!

```
function someFunction() 
{
var element = angular.element("#id here");
element.focus()
}
```

For you, the following may work:

```
function onAddButtonClicked() 
{
   var element = angular.element("#circleTimeWordListEditText");
   element.focus()
}
```

Comment: Please tell us why the issue is gone. Thanks!

Comment: For me this worked. I wanted to focus a particular element. So, I added the id to it and by getting that particular element with id using angular.element and setting the focus to that element, the issue is solved for me.

Comment: you can check this link :) 

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/vJQXtsZiX4EJ6Uvw9xtG?p=preview&preview